# Samsung J7 (2017): How to turn on typing suggestions yet keep autoreplace disabled?

Tags: keyboard, auto-correct, samsung-galaxy-j7

Not sure if I'm using the right terms here. By typing suggestions I mean the horizontal word bar that stays right above my keyboard and suggests which words I may be trying to type. And by autoreplace I mean that when I mistype a word and press space, the keyboard auto-replaces my word with what it thinks I meant.

My device appears to bundle both options into one, which either on or off:

[image]

This worked as I want it OOTB in my old Samsung J3 (2016).

Answer (score 0):

I just installed Gboard and it works the way I want.